# JTooltips is not working IE browser

Tags: internet-explorer, joomla1.5

Joomla 1.5.23 Jtooltip is not  working fine in  IE browser.

the error I am getting is;

```
 showcaseFX.js, line 1 character 7454
 SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'getElements': object is null or undefined
```

Comment: Thats really a great question .If u have already found the answer,please post it

Comment: ok, I have not yet found the answer